# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str data set question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Please help Ive spent three hours on stack now i tried ''.join, str, removing the "+" for "," and nothing works to remove this error! The last 2 comments is where the error happens!
#Description: Build a anime recommendation using python
#Store the data
df = pd.read_csv('animes.csv')
#Show the first 3 rows of data
df.head(2)

```
    #Count of the number of rows/animes in the data set and the number oof colums
    df.shape
    
    
    #List of wanted columns for anime recommendations
    columns =['title','synopsis','genre','aired','episodes']
    
    #Data updated
    df[columns].head(3)
    
    #Missing values check
    df[columns].isnull().values.any()
    
    #Create a funtion to combine the values of the new columns into a single string
    def get_new_features(data):
      new_features =[]
      for i in range (0, data.shape[0]):
         new_features.append(data['title'][i]+''+data['synopsis'][i]+''+data['genre'][i]+''+data['aired'][i]+''+data['episodes'][i])
    
         return new_features
     
    
    
     #Create a column to hold combine strings
     df ['new_features'] = get_new_features(df)
    
     #show data
     df.head(4)

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-97-d5676456ab85> in <module>()
          1 #Create a column to hold combine strings
    ----> 2 df ['new_features'] = get_new_features(df)
          3 
          4 #show data
          5 df.head(4)
    
    <ipython-input-95-842623950c0e> in get_new_features(data)
          3   new_features =[]
          4   for i in range (0, data.shape[0]):
    ----> 5      new_features.append(data['title'][i]+''+data['synopsis'][i]+''+data['genre'][i]+''+data['aired'][i]+''+data['episodes'][i])
          6 
          7      return new_features
    
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str
```

Comment: Why are you adding single strings there? In general, it helps if you extract a [mcve] as well, just to make clear which string concatenation (`+` operator) is causing the issue and what the left and right operand are. My guess: Use string formatting (`f"ab{var}cd{other_var}ef"`). As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Ah, also search for the error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+TypeError%3A+can+only+concatenate+str

Comment: `5+' '` will produce this error.  So one or more of the `data[column][i]` is a number instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I would print `data` to see what items/types it contain.

```py
for key, value in data.items():
    print(value)
    print(key)
    print(type(data[key]))
```

Using this output you should be able to discern what areas in `data` you need to convert to string or change the formatting of.
Most likely you can do the lazy route of just casting each item to string:

```py
new_features.append(str(data['title'][i])+''+str(data['synopsis'][i])+''+str(data['genre'][i])+''+str(data['aired'][i])+''+str(data['episodes'][i]))
```